# Does cfn-init need to be called from UserData?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

It seems that `AWS::CloudFormation::Init` has a config section which has `files` and `commands` subsections. But there is also the Base64-encoded `UserData` in `Properties` which calls `cfn-init` in a sample script that I have:

```
"Fn::Base64": {
    "Fn::Join": [
        "",
        [
            "<script>\n",
            "cfn-init.exe -v -s ", {
                "Ref": "AWS::StackId"
            },
            " -r MyInstance",
            " --region ", {
                "Ref": "AWS::Region"
            },
            "\n",
..................
```

My question is - do you need to manually call `cfn-init` from `UserData` in order to execute the instructions in `AWS::CloudFormation::Init`? If so, why is that? Why not start it automatically so the config section always gets executed if present?

Answer (score 2):

`cfn-init.exe` is the local component on the EC2 instances that communicates back to the CloudFormation stack to execute the commands inside the `AWS::CloudFormation::Init` section.

I don't know, but I believe the reason it doesn't put the actual script inside the User Data is that it doesn't want to modify the User Data in case you have your own scripts in there. Also, the commands to execute could be dynamic from the parameters passed into your CloudFormation script. The `cfn-init.exe` tool can read these values and make smart choices about how to run the `AWS::CloudFormation::Init` commands.

More information on what `cfn-init.exe` does here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-init.html